# How to force nested npm dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies, nested, npm

I believe this is pretty common question, but still I could not find reliable answer.

In my package.json I have dependency - "grunt-selenium-webdriver", which has some dependency version listed in its package.json  which is not accessible from our network (we are using internal NPM registry which lags sometimes).

I want to use current version of grunt-selenium-webdriver but with different version of nested dependency.
Is this possible anyhow?

PS: I tried peer dependencies, but it seems that it aims to solve another issue.

Comment: you can `edit package.json` file, as per your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by [NPM-Shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-shrinkwrap) functionality.

Other examples can be found on [managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/).